# What is preventing widespread use of XSLT for webpages?

Tags: xml, xslt

Why aren't more webpages written using XML with an XSLT stylesheet?  For separating content from presentation, this combined with CSS would be even more powerful.  Right now, for things like outputting a navigation menu, people often hand-copy the navmenu code from page to page or do something like

```
<?php include_once('myheader.inc'); ?>
```

on every page, which not only puts more demand on the server, but results in duplicated data transmitted.

When I was introduced to it, I was told that all major browsers back to IE6 support XSLT 1.0... are there unresolvable bugs between implementations?   Are there others showstoppers or severely lacking features that are inhibiting the spread of XML+XSLT?  The only website I've seen lately that is XML+XSLT is starcraft2.com.

Comment: Have you ever tried to manage variables in XSLT?

Comment: Its far to clunky to use plus programming in XML is painful.  Academics love XML + XSLT but in business it is rarely used.

Comment: Same question as... [Why has XSLT never seen the popularity of many other languages that came out during the internet boom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77342/why-has-xslt-never-seen-the-popularity-of-many-other-languages-that-came-out-duri)

Comment: Didn't see your question, posted a slightly different one, but the answers will probably be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270573/is-there-any-future-in-xslt

Comment: Nosrama - whilst the clunky comment may be valid, it's certainly not true that XML + XSLT is rarely used. Maybe less so for web pages but they're used a lot for back end transformations.

Comment: @JBKing If you use variables in XSLT then you do something wrong here. XSLT is declarative and should be used in a functional approach.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. It is extremely verbose
2. It is hard to trace (in a complex system) how/where/why/when a template is called
3. Since the output must be well-formed you can't have a template that "opens" the HEAD or BODY tag that you'll then worry about closing somewhere else later.  This sucks when you want to be able to queue up bits of code to go into the HEAD when you are processing what will be in the BODY.
4. It isn't as easy to navigate the code as following method calls is
5. Outputting something like an IE conditional comment is very confusing with all the escaping needed
6. Building a string of HTML by appending bits just doesn't work.  This can be overcome by building the HTML string bit by bit in XSL code, but it becomes quite complex.

However most of all (IMHO) it adds an extra layer to the process that doesn't "buy" you much.

e.g. typically you have:

```
DB > SQL > [JAVA|PHP|ASP|Python|Ruby] > HTML
```

but if you throw XML and XSL in, you've added steps that (can be) hard to justify

```
DB > SQL > [JAVA|PHP|ASP|Python|Ruby] > XML > XSL > HTML
```

having the data in a handy dandy universally exchangeable XML format is great-n-all, but unless you **need** it, all you've done is add steps.

Now I shouldn't knock XSL too much because, well I use it all the time and do appreciate some of the powerful options it provides.  However to anyone deciding if they want to use it, be sure you have a **need** before diving in.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you.  I don't know who thought it would be great to take markup like html or xml which is already verbose and difficult to read and embed more markup but this time with complex branching and looping.  The thought scares me.

Comment: Your point of "DB>SQL>[JAVA|PHP|ASP|Python|Ruby]>XML>XSL>HTML" is well taken. But when you DO need it, it is awesome. If you wanted to provide a web page and a web service with the same back end, only the XSL presentation code would have to change.

Comment: Not extremely, just verbose. XSLT has it's places - esp. where there's an existing XML output, you can make a web from it with almost no effort.

Comment: Re: "extremely" I guess it depends on your perspective. If I compare the code needed to take an XML nodeSet and render an HTML Select list with logic to select the "current" value etc. - vs. what it would take me to output a list/map in PHP/Ruby/etc. the difference is pretty obvious to me.

Comment: I think your statement: `DB > SQL > [JAVA|PHP|ASP|Python|Ruby] > XML > XSL > HTML` is more correctly `DB > SQL > [few lines Java|PHP|etc] > XSL > [HTML|PDF|XML|PS|etc]` and therein lies the attraction of something like XSL.  The book [Java and XML by Brett McLauglin](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101497.do) written years ago covered.  With the rise of mobile web, we are just now seeing that McLauglin's book was quite prophetic.  I do agree that XSL is complex and iText have leaped past Apache FOP, and perhaps judicious use of js and css have gotten us a little towards the idea of xsl?

Comment: Did you mean: `DB > SQL > [few lines Java|PHP|etc] > XML > XSL > [HTML|PDF|XML|PS|etc]` ?  While I totally agree that there is power in having a structured document format (XML) that can be parsed into pretty much anything via XSL I've not seen many implementations that show these abilities in impressive ways.

Answer (score 7):

Blizzard Entertainment seems to like XSLT.  Their [World of Warcraft Armory](http://wowarmory.com/) site is completely implemented using it.  Look around the site using view source.

Comment: Why was this voted down? It's a very good example of one of  the very few sites that use XSTL extensively for their website

Comment: Because it is WoW.  People can't seem to separate their emotions about the game and its tech.

Comment: I think the WoW remote Armory web site was implemented largely with XLST at the time; several years ago;.  Blizzard later rewrote the whole remote armory shebang when it moved it over from wowarmory.com to us.battle.net; or whatever your place is if it is not US.  Today, I took a look at character and found that the new implementation of the site uses CSS stylesheets, JavaScript including the jQuery library, and I even noticed a little Flash incantation in one corner of the source code for the web page.

Answer (score 6):

I think part of the issue is that programming in XSLT has some of the attributes of a functional language (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110031/is-xslt-a-functional-programming-language) for why it's not fully functional).

As such it requires a different approach from the 'usual' imperative mindset, and that will deter some people from fully investigating it (I'm not dismissing functional programming, btw, but in the web client/server world it's not the most common paradigm).

In the Java world it used to be perceived as being slow and memory hungry. I'm sure some of that was anecdotal, and perhaps partly the effect of early VMs. I note, however, that hardware XML accelerators are [available](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/datapower/xa35/) and sit behind the JAXP interface, so perhaps there's still a speed issue ?

Comment: +1 Put simply, XSLT is a pain in the ass to use for all but certain narrow tasks.

Comment: I wouldn't be so rude :-), but after being told that the way to manipulate XML in Ant was to use XSLT, I developed XMLTask (Google it) to do XML in Ant. Horses for courses, etc.!

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues regarding the adoption of XSLT, browser issues among others. For instance, the Firefox plugin NoScript, designed for blocking malicious JavaScript, also blocks XSLT on unknown pages. Don't forget that switching to a subdomain or different protocol will make IE respond to it as a violation of the same origin policy. Still, XML+XSLT, even though it's just for a limited number of cases, is quite useful. See [WoW](http://www.worldofwarcraft.com/index.xml)'s website as an example of well-implemented XML+XSLT.

Comment: Starcraft2 and WoW both being Blizzard properties, we've come up with a grand total of 1 company that uses it. :(

Answer (score 4):

XSLT isn't easy.

Comment: Too hard... sorry but that doesn't cut it.

Comment: I'm just a simple man in a high tech digital world, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wY5bLLXMUgQ

Comment: It's not that it isn't easy, it just requires a different way of thinking. It's a rule based rather than procedural language. If you can think rule based, it's not all that hard.

For data transformation it's more logical and effective than procedural statements.

Answer (score 3):

XSL in the browser is also a problem because of search engines. Currently, they only look at the underlying XML and ignore the XSL stylesheet. That seriously hurts your ranking, I suppose, since they can't make any sense of your content that way. Like, they wouldn't even know where the headings or links are for example.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, XSLT is far too complicated.

Comment: Too hard... sorry but that doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT in the browser is right out because the smallest mistake in generating valid XML input could cause your page to show up blank, but there's a product called [deliverance](http://deliverance.openplans.org/) that runs on the server to make different web applications in a site share the same theme.

XSLT is surprisingly fast. It will be much faster than a typical interpreted templating language on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is an ugly, ugly template language. It has some advantages, but is also missing some critical features. [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs) features a template language for designers to give them simple access to data elements. They have considered [XLST before](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/610), but consider it simple to change out. PHP users may prefer something like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Obviously your question focuses on moving this to the browser, where the choices are basically XSLT, CSS or Javascript. I'm guessing the people who are in charge of CSS are not the same as those in charge of Javascripting.

Comment: XSLT is anything but a "template language". It bears no resemblance it "something like Smarty" *whatsoever*. If you think that's what XSLT is for then you are completely on the wrong track.

Comment: XSLT is for writing templates and placing data from XML in it. The  difference between smarty and XSLT is that XSLT requires XML input, and requires that XSLT itself be XML compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do a piss poor job of rendering XSLT... meaning that to get it to render properly across browser, you need to render it on the server, negating any advantage you had for using it in the first place.

This means that you end up doing two conversions on the server side instead of one: data -> XML -> HTML instead of data -> HTML.

Comment: Actually, no, Electro did NOT point out that browsers do a poor job rendering XSLT.  He only said that security is strictly enforced.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT was one of the few XMLish technologies that I actually liked.  Especially for report generation the concept of XSLT with its set-based feel and ability to target all kinds of output formats (not just html) it deserves to be used more than it is today.

The reason I personally never used it was because at the time one of the browsers (I believe IE7) did not support rendering XSLT in the browser and we did not have the option of XSLT processing on the server side.

The second reason is that while its great for reporting and data presentation it wasn't really practical in terms of general purpose use.

Answer (score 0):

People who didn't live under a rock for the last ten years don't copy and paste header code or use PHP includes for layout anymore. They separate presentation from the actual code and use templating systems (eg. Smarty, a popular one for PHP) which have syntax that is easier to comprehend and reason about than XSLT.

Comment: It's easier to convince somebody to use a templating system than XSLT, especially when it comes to designers and front-end developers.